# .net core - Separation of WebApp and EF Data Layer not working

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-core, database-migration

I am trying to create a new project in .net core. I want to have all the EF related things in my Data project like below:

```
Solution
-- Project.Data
-- Project.WebApp
-- Project.AnotherWebApp
```

Unfortunately I am getting the following error:

When trying to run the migration (*dotnet ef migrations add init*) on the Data project I am getting this error:

> Could not invoke this command on the startup project 'MyProject.Data'.
>   This preview of Entity Framework tools does not support commands on
>   class library projects in ASP.NET Core and .NET Core applications. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798221 for details and
>   workarounds.

Unfortunately both workarounds that are explained in the link do not work..

On the other hand when running the migration command on the WebApp I am getting this error:
Your target project 'MyProject.Portal' doesn't match your migrations assembly 'MyProject.Data'. Either change your target project or change your migrations assembly.

> Change your migrations assembly by using DbContextOptionsBuilder. E.g.
>   options.UseSqlServer(connection, b =>
>   b.MigrationsAssembly("MyProject.Portal")). By default, the migrations
>   assembly is the assembly containing the DbContext. Change your target
>   project to the migrations project by using the Package Manager
>   Console's Default project drop-down list, or by executing "dotnet ef"
>   from the directory containing the migrations project.

How can I get this to work, ideally so that I can run the migrations on the Data project?!

Thank you very much for your help,
Nik

Comment: What happens when you try the workarounds?  I have had no problems doing this.

Comment: Which workaround did you use please? Both workarounds require a Main function, is that correct?

Comment: From memory i believe it's Workaround 1.  I created a blank ASP.NET Core Web App and then removed all the stuff I didn't need.  You do need a `Main` function and `Startup` class to configure your DbContext.  The workarounds could be a bit more detailed.

Comment: I will give it another try! Thanks Brad. Do you know by any chance when this will be fixed? I have tried to install the tooling preview3 but that did not even let me compile my projects anymore..

Comment: That's probably a question best directed at the EF Core team.  The non-RTM versioning of libraries and tools combined with incomplete documentation doesn't make it easy.  There shouldn't have to be workarounds.  Hopefully everything is more stable when all parts are full RTM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I get this to work, ideally so that I can run the migrations on the Data project?!

Entity Framework Core does not currently support running migrations on a class library, because the migrations require an application. The following workaround creates an application that has only one job: to run the migrations.

[Here is a GitHub sample project](https://github.com/bigfont/StackOverflow/tree/master/AspNetCoreEntityFrameworkMigrations).

## The Data Layer

This is a really simple data layer that contains the context and a simple entity.

#### Datalayer/MyContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DataLayer
{
    public class MyDataModel 
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<MyDataModel> MyDataModels { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### Datalayer/project.json

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "netstandard1.6": {}
    }
}
```

## The Data Layer Migration App

This small program runs the migrations.

We run both `dotnet ef migrations...` and `dotnet ef database...` from this project's directory. Both commands use `ConfigureServices` while creating migrations and updating the database.

The `Configure` method is NOT necessary to run either the migrations or the update. Rather, it's there strictly to let us do a test read of the database with `dotnet run`.

#### Datalayer.Migrations/Program.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using DataLayer;

namespace DataLayer.Migrations
{
    public class Program
    {
        private readonly IConfigurationRoot _configuration;

        public Program()
        {
            _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json")
                .Build();
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseStartup<Program>()
                .Build();
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {   
            var currentAssembly = "DataLayer.Migrations";
            var connectionString = 
                _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

            services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(optionsBuilder =>
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(
                    connectionString,
                    builder => builder.MigrationsAssembly(currentAssembly));
            });
        }

        public void Configure(MyContext context)
        {    
            var data = new MyDataModel
            {
                Id = System.Guid.NewGuid()
            };

            context.Add(data);
            context.SaveChanges();

            var count = context.MyDataModels.CountAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine($"There are {count} items.");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Datalayer.Migrations/appsettings.json

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": 
            "Filename=MyDatabase.sqlite"
    }
}
```

#### Datalayer.Migrations/project.json

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "buildOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true,
        "copyToOutput": {
            "include": [
                "appsettings.json"
            ]
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "DataLayer": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
            "type": "build",
            "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
        }
    },
    "tools": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "netcoreapp1.0": {
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
                    "type": "platform",
                    "version": "1.0.1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed answer Shaun. I see that the DataLayer project is using .net standart in your example. Can this also be .net core to make it cross platform? Also using your solution means that I can simply regard the Migrations project once the EF core team have fixed that problem (running migrations,etc on class libs)? Thanks again!

Comment: @user2118781 To answer your first question, `netstandard` is cross-platform so you do not need to change anything to make it cross-platform.

Comment: @user2118781 What do you mean by "simply regard the Migrations project?"

Comment: I mean once the EF Core team have fixed the issue that the EF CLI Tools can't run migrations etc on class libs? It is a filed bug and will hopefully be fixed with the next major release (https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5320). So once that is fixed the Migrations project could be removed from my solution, correct? Thanks very much for your advise and help!

Comment: @user2118781 From reading the post that you linked, it would seem that yes, if the EF Core team enables running `dotnet ef migrations` against a class library, then you will be able to remove the migrations project from your solution and run the migrations directly against the class library.

Comment: One last question please. I have successfully implemented your suggested solution. Thanks again. Everything works perfectly when running locally. When publishing to my Azure site the migrations are not automatically applied. Is there an easy way to achieve this also? Thanks.

Comment: @user2118781 At this point I suggest opening another question on StackOverflow, because automatically running migrations is an involved answer.